# Sorting values with two columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns; `country` and `price`. The first 10 values are shown below. I would like to sort the prices such I can be able to get the top 20 highest prices. Kindly help.

Thanks.

```
head(df,10)

# Country Price
# 1      US 235
# 2   Spain 110
# 3      US  90
# 4      US  65
# 5  France  66
# 6   Spain  73
# 7   Spain  65
# 8   Spain 110
# 9      US  65
# 10     US  60
```

Comment: Need more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `top_n`

```
n1 <- 5
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     top_n(n1, Price) %>%
     select(Country)
```

If it should be based on each 'Country', do a grouping by 'Country'

```
df %>%
   group_by(Country) %>%
   top_n(n1, Price) %>%
   select(Country)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I extract the column with countries a lone?

Comment: @MicahOndiwa you can use `select` (updated thhe post)